# How to find Java Script in PDF document in .NET Core?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, pdf

I need to implement on the server side(.NET Core) the ability to check the PDF document for the presence of Java Scripts. If there is a script there, then I need to inform user about it. Is it possible to do this without using paid libraries?
I will be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: you can use iTextSharp to read the PDF files in .NET Core.

Comment: iTextSharp license cost too much

Comment: Any good general purpose pdf library should do.

Answer (score 0):

Cross platform poppler utils is the simplest to use, There is no guarantee any means will find deliberately obscured JavaScript

```
pdfinfo -js filename.pdf
```

will output as plain text any standard embedded JavaScript, thus if the text looks obscured you can be forewarned of an oddity.

***A common PDF with normal `/JavaScript` entry will show up by simple plain text search.***

for suspect or compressed file objects a simple extension is to use a pdf decompressor (Internal streams must be decompressed if required to show up any content as plain text) and text search for the `/JavaScript` marker as here for example:-

```
<</S/JavaScript/JS(\n\r\n\r\n// T
```

However an article about say PDF exploitation could legitimately contain this text
`Td [(/JavaScript)]TJ`

and it is easy for JS to self-edit at run time so this would not be detected in such a simple manner  `/JavaScr##69pt`

You may find of interest page 4 of    [https://web.archive.org/web/20150421225342if_/http://cs.gmu.edu:80/~astavrou/research/Daiping_dsn14.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20150421225342if_/http://cs.gmu.edu:80/%7Eastavrou/research/Daiping_dsn14.pdf)

For a similar question (aimed at PHP) with variable answers see [Find malicious PDF files using PHP validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615324/find-malicious-pdf-files-using-php-validation)

Answer (score 0):

use PDFsharp and MigraDoc, it is free to use as it is open source (http://www.pdfsharp.net/Licensing.ashx)